# Infinite Scroll does not trigger ionInfinite method in case of only single item in first load

Tags: ionic4, infinite-scroll

I am using Ionic 4 and Angular 10, am loading loading data date-wise and working fine but at first-time load single record of the day, infinite scroll does not trigger ioninfinte method.

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" class="ion-padding">


<ion-list>

<ion-item *ngFor="let employee of itemListData">
  <ion-avatar slot="start">
    <img [src]="employee.imageUrl">
  </ion-avatar>
  <ion-label>
    <ion-text>
      <h2>{{employee.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{employee.jobtype}}</p>
    </ion-text>
    <ion-text color="medium">
      <p>{{employee.email}}, {{employee.address}}</p>
    </ion-text>
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
<ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
</ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: Why would you need to load more data if there is only a single item in the first load ? Surely you don't want to load items one by one.

Comment: Share your ts file code...

Comment: @Reqven I think the user can understand that he will get data one by one date on every scrolling. API already works in android so I cannot change it.

Comment: @user9088454 I think ts file is not required. However, I will create a fresh demo and share it.

Comment: Ok, that is also fine...